# Validate and Update database from html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, database

I have prepared a dashboard where the data will be displayed in html table from a database. However, If any user wants to edit the same table, then he need to click the cell and update the content. So that it should update the same in database. Please help me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question and most likely will be voted to get closed, however, you need to start somewhere.

I would use something like [jq grid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)

It includes the ability to edit and delete rows within a table. You're going to need some sort of back end services to handle the CRUD requests though.

Comment: Thanks Jack. I need to explore the link provided by u. I'll and get back to u.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the simple way would be, if you give an unique ID for every row in database, and then in HTML table put some edit button, and hidden input label with unique ID as value, so you can use $POST and open every row on some "edit page". In edit page you can call all values from database to inputs, so you can edit them and send them back to base.

Then you can simply use query like:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE databasename . tablename SET input1='$input1', input2='$input2', input3='$input3',  WHERE tablename . id='$id'");
```